# Umbraco page went blank after a while

Tags: umbraco

I noticed there are two ways to see this problem, 
one is wait a time (1 hour more or less) and two with the option "Republish entire site".
I tried deleting content node, doc type and template; and recreating again.

Also there is no error displayed with ?umbDebugShowTrace=true, the page has no parent it's directly under Content.

Any help will be great.
Thanks.

Umbraco version is 4.11.5

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious reason why a page would be blank would be if you have not set a valid template - or have subsequently deleted the template.  Check the properties tab towards the top to see if there is a template for the node.

The second most obvious would be if you were adding a doctype that wasn't an allowed child type of the parent - you could do this by adding it as an allowable child, and then later removing this right from the second tab of the doctype setup.

Not much to go on really.